# Direct TCP/IP Communication

Tags: tcp, dns

I have two applications running on two seperate servers.  For them to work together there is a requirement for them to be within the same domain and can therefore (as I understand it) communicate directly, without a router.  How do I prove that they are a) in the same domain (should be pretty simple based on IP?)  b) can communicate directly

Thanks, Andy.

Comment: You may be thinking of the term "[broadcast domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain)" (not DNS domain). Hosts in the same broadcast domain can communicate without a router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is a requirement for them to be within the same domain and can therefore (as I understand it) communicate directly, without a router.

Wrong. They can communicate without a router if they are in the same subnet, which merely requires that they have the same subnet mask, and can ping each other. Being in the same domain has nothing to do with it.

> How do I prove that they are a) in the same domain (should be pretty simple based on IP?)

Being in the same domain is a function of their respective domain names: they should share a common suffix longer than .com. IP address has nothing to do with it.

> b) can communicate directly

They need to have the same subnet mask.

Off topic.